# Storing templated derived classes in container

Tags: c++, templates, generics, design-patterns

I have a series of field validators that each look something like the following:

```
template <typename T>
class NameValidator : public Validator<T> {

    ...
    bool validate(const T& msg) const override { ... }
    ...

};
```

Each of these validators must be able to validate different message types, hence the template parameter `T`.

I would like to create a manager class that serves as a common gateway to each of these validators. Something like the following:

```
class ValidatorManger {

    ...
    // Calls validate() functions for each field.
    template <typename T>
    bool validate(const T& msg) { ... }
    ...

};
```

Hence, I will need to store each of the validator classes (ex: `NameValidator<T>`) in some type of data structure and then iterate over them within `ValidatorManager::validate()`.

Is there a way to do this so that I do not have to explicitly specialize the templates for each message type? I'm imaging something like the following

```
validator_map.insert(std::make_pair("Name", NameValidator<T>));
validator_map.insert(std::make_pair("Age", AgeValidator<T>());
...
```

though this is obviously gibberish.

**Questions:**

- Has anyone used this sort of pattern before and have a solution for achieving this?
- Should I be rethinking this design entirely?

Comment: It's possible to have a tuple and iterate over that.

Comment: Why are the special validators e.g NameValidator a template? Shouldn't it derive from Validator<string> or whatever type it should validate?

Comment: @chris -- could you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: @ZivS -- No. The template parameter `T` is the type of the message, not the type of the underlying thing being validated (which, in general, is not just a simple primitive).

Comment: @Ryan Rereading the question, I expect you want a tuple of `vector<Validator<T>>` for each possible `T`. The tuple stores each vector, which is a different type. `validate` gets the vector using the message type with `std::get<T>(tuple)` and receives a vector of validators for that message type, which I expect would look like max66's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a container that you can food with instructions like

```
validator_map.insert(std::pair("Name", NameValidator<T>()));
validator_map.insert(std::pair("Age", AgeValidator<T>()));
```

you need that your type `T` is known, othewise `NameValidator<T>` isn't a type and `NameValidator<T>()` can't initialize an object.

So I suppose that your `validator_map` should be a variable (static?) inside the template `validator()` method in `ValidatorManager`.

So, hoping that can be semplified, the best I can imagine is in the following example

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Validator 
 { virtual bool validate (T const &) const = 0; };

template <typename T>
struct NameValidator : public Validator<T>
 {
   bool validate (T const & msg) const override
    { std::cout << "- name (" << msg << ")" << std::endl; return true; }
 };

template <typename T>
struct AgeValidator : public Validator<T>
 {
   bool validate (T const & msg) const override
    { std::cout << "- age  (" << msg << ")" << std::endl; return true; }
 };

struct ValidatorManager
 {
   template <typename T>
   bool validate (T const & msg) const
    {
      static bool first {true};
      static std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Validator<T>>> vvt;

      if ( first )
       {
         vvt.emplace_back( new NameValidator<T>{} );
         vvt.emplace_back( new AgeValidator<T>{} );

         first = false;
       }

      bool ret { true };

      for ( auto const & v : vvt )
         ret &= v->validate(msg);

      return ret;
    }
 };

int main()
 {
   ValidatorManager  vm;

   vm.validate(1);
   vm.validate(2.2);
   vm.validate("3.3");
 }
```